# Managing subdomains

Tags: python, django, subdomain

What are the best practices and solutions for managing dynamic subdomains in different technologies and frameworks? I am searching for something to implement in my Django project but those solutions that I saw, don't work. I also tried to use Apache rewrite mod to send requests from subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/subdomain but couldn't realize how to do it with Django.

**UPDATE:** What I need is to create virtual subdomains for my main domain using usernames from the site. So, if I have a new registered user that is called jack, when I go to jack.domain.com, it would operate make some operations. Like if I just went to domain.com/users/jack. But I don't want to create an actual subdomain for each user.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to answer if you described what you mean by "managing" them and what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do what you need with apache mod_rewrite.

Obviously I didn't read the question clearly enough.

As for how to do it in django: you could have some middleware that looks at the server name, and redirects according to that (or even sets a variable). You can't do it with the bare url routing system, as that only has path information, not hostname info.